# how to Import products automatic in different domain?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am working on magento 1.7 version.I have different stores and I need to sync all products and orders of different magento stores with my main magento store.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools available for importing data into Magento.  Syncing between two Magento installs would be a lot more complicated, but it can be done with enough effort.

Look into setting up [Magmi: Magento Mass Importer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) for importing products into Magento and using the PHP-CLI interface along with an automatic cron-job to schedule automatic imports into your Magento install.